# Recibir datos de un stored procedure en c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Quisiera saber como puedo obtener un dato del stored procedure en sql server y luego insertarlo en una variable tipo `int` en c#.

Ya yo escribí un código que me tiene que devolver el `ID` mayor que tengo en mi tabla, pero el código que escribí recibe como respuesta `"1"`

Este es mi stored procedure:

```
create procedure NumId  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  MAX(id) AS id  FROM dbo.ProductsData 
END
go
execute numID
```

Este es código en c#:

```
 string spq = "NumId";                                                                            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spq, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            tblData[5, i].Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Esa linea esta ahi por que estaba borrando un codigo, pero a parecer no lo borre por completo

Comment: Para empezar. Tu stored procedure devuelve un resultado, con lo que no necesitas un `SqlDataReader` ni un bucle. Simplemente, ejecuta `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` y eso debería devolverte el resultado de tu procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: Cambie el codigo, pero la respuesta del stored procedure es la misma "1"  este es el codigo que cambie:  ´SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spq, con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    tblData[5, i].Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());´

Comment: no, cuando lo ejecuto en sql server me da el numero correcto

Comment: Acabo de hacer un ejemplo en mi servidor, con exactamente el mismo código y funciona perfectamente. Mira a ver si tu conexion con el servidor es correcta (que no te estes conectando a algun servidor de prueba o algo asi) y tambien que el problema no esté en el paso a `tblData`. haz `var resultado = cmd.ExecuteScalar();` y depura lo que hay en `resultado`.

Comment: No entiendo algunas cosas,  tengo que crea un `DataTable` ? y a que te refieres con  la coneccion del servidor de prueba?   Yo depure el stored procedure y me da `"1"`, pero la consulta que se encuentra en el stored procedure me da el numero correcto

Comment: sabes que no se como paso pero como que por arte de magia el stored procedure se arreglo, le hice debug( sin hacer ningun cambio) despues del debug se arreglo

Comment: @Mike como es eso de que un stored procedure no regresa nada? El del op regresa el resultado correcto, el mayor id de la tabla

Comment: que regrese datos no significa que sea una buena practica

Comment: @Mike me puedes enlazar alguna documentación donde se especifique que es una mala práctica un procedimiento almacenado que hace un `Select` y llamarlo con `ExecuteScalar`? Sin acritud :)

Comment: hmmm sigo sin encontrar fuentes... empiezo a pensar que he estado viviendo una mentira por mucho tiempo....

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo que cada vez que quieras obtener datos de un SELECT en un SP lo hagas a través del método ExecuteReader() y luego iteres sobre el recordset devuelto

```
try
{
    cnn.Open();
    string spq = "NumId";                                                                            
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spq, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             tblData[5, i].Value = Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0}", reader['id']));
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    cnn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
}
```

Comment: Como ya le dije al op en un comentario, depende del procedimiento almacenado. En el caso que expone el op, no tiene sentido ya que siempre va a devolver una única fila con una única columna, asi que usar un DataReader no tiene absolutamente ningun sentido